# Нарочно заданные вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Как правильней относиться к вопросу (ну и к автору) на который ответил он сам.

> Но меньше чем за 10 или вообще за 5 минут после заданного вопроса

Но это не про `примитивные` вопросы я говорю, а про те что если не знать хоть на какую сторону двигаться то можешь потерять часы для того что бы достичь результата.

Comment: Как относиться .. хорошо относиться!